# Accessing `this` within data argument of jQuery `on` Event Handler

Tags: jquery

I am working on a project that uses jQuery's `on` Event Handler to throw an click event.  I am using an event handler to handle the outcome and passing it some data through, but I need access to `this` within my data setting.  Is it possible to get a reference to what element was clicked on?

```
$listOfLinks = $('body a');
$listOfLinks.on('click', {
    'element': this.classList.contains('btn') ? 'Button!' : 'Link?',
    'text': this.innerText
}, stuffEventHandler );
```

[jQuery docs for `on` Event Handler](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Why not just do those evaluations in your `stuffEventHandler` instead of trying to work them in to the `data` argument? The problem is that your `data` object is evaluated when you call `on`, not when the click event occurs

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: This is one piece of a more complicated setup.  I am trying to make a single event handler that can handle any number of listeners.  The more data setting I can do within the listener, the more agnostic my handler can be.

Answer (score 1):

You could send a function as data. For example instead of

```
'element': this.classList.contains('btn') ? 'Button!' : 'Link?'
```

You would pass something like:

```
'findElement': function(context){
  return context.classList.contains('btn') ? 'Button!' : 'Link?'
}
```

Then from your handler you call it with this `findElement(this)`